# Verify node exists before getting its value

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I Stored the xml values in one string using C#.

```
string abcd="<xstructure><a>
   <a1>1</a1>
   <a2>2</a2>
   <a3>3</a3>
</a>

<b>4</b>
</xstructure>";
```

I retrieved the xml values from the string like,

```
 var xElem = XElement.Parse(abcd);
 string b= xElem.Element("b").Value;
```

it was working fine.How to Check the Xml Node Exist in the XML Structure or Not?**if i try to get the C value from the structure the C value does not exist in the XML structure.So i need to check the c value available or not,before i try to get the C value**.How can I do this?

Comment: Not valid xml, there must be only one root node.

Comment: @ChuckSavage now check that structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
XElement c = xElem.Element("c");
if(null != c)
{
   // do something with c because it exists, like...
   string cValue = c.Value;
}
```